# Push segue is causing my iOS app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

As can be seen in the screenshot below, when I click next in the Search View Controller to transition to the criteria view controller on the right, my app crashes. I recieve an error stating  the following:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'`

What about my setup is incorrect? I want it so that a user inputs an item name, clicks next, and is then taken to the criteria page to specify additional info.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your "Search View Controller" and on the top toolbar select Editor->Embed In->UINavigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Search view controller` should be inside navigation controller (currently your destination controller is navigation controller)

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order (the switch the segue connections) of the `Search View Controller` and the `Navigation Controller`. Then set the `Navigation Controller`'s root view controller to be `Search View Controller`.